# Shorcut key to open emoji picker on VS Code on Windows 7 not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

My VS Code cannot open the emoji picker box.

I tried pressing: <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>.

None of that is working.

How can I open it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Edit` menu, last entry - `Emoji & Symbols`.

It will also tell you what the shortcut key is.

**UPDATE:**

Just installed 1.60 on my Windows 10. There is no menu item for Emoji, but `WinKey`+`.` works for me.

Sorry, can't try on Windows 7...

**UPDATE 2:**

Looked and the VSCode shortcut key binding (`Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S`) and didn't find emoji there.

On a hunch tried `Win+.` in the Visual Studio and got the same Emoji popup - this is apparently a Win10 hot key...

Comment: I have checked and I can't find `Emoji & Symbols` inside `Edit` menu. Here is what I have [edit menu](https://imgur.com/gallery/RXgCKm2)

Comment: is it possibly because my Windows 7 doesn't suport emojis?

Comment: @Gamintor My menu looks different. What is your version of Visual Code?

Comment: My VS Code version is 1.60.0

Comment: @Gamintor please see my update in this answer.

Comment: So, I can't use emojis on Windows 7?!

Comment: @Gamintor - well, there are various VSCode extensions that do that... But honestly, WHY would you need emoji in your code???

Comment: I installed `Emoji Snippets` VS Code extension and I can use emojis now. I also had to install a Windows 7 update for the Segoe UI symbol font. I can only have black and white emojis but still, it's better than nothing. And big thanks Mr. Feinstein for trying to help me!